# How can I make this Query faster? Is Left Outer Joins / Inner Joins the fastest way to approach the required dataset in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the following query, and it takes around 3-4 seconds to complete. I need this to return results in less than a second if possible.

I'm not sure if the Inner Joins and Outer joins are the best to use in this situation. Maybe using Cross Apply?

How can I approach this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT QH.SupplierCode AS SupplierCode,
                BP.Name AS SupplierName,
                BP.ShortName AS SupplierShortName,
                QH.BillingSupplierCode AS BillingSupplierCode,
                BillingSupplierBP.ShortName AS BillingSupplierShortName,
                QH.QuotationNum,
                QH.CurrencyCode,
                CONVERT(MONEY, QH.PackagingExpenses + QH.DeliveryExpenses + QH.OtherExpenses) AS PDOExpenses,
                ISNULL(ER.ExchangeRate, CASE
                                            WHEN QH.CurrencyCode =
                                                   (SELECT BaseCurrencyCode
                                                    FROM ApplicationProfile) THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0
                                        END) AS ExchangeRate,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 8), 0) AS TotalNetValue,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 8), 0) AS TotalNetValueForCommonItems,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 8), 0) AS TotalDiscountValue,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(30, 8), 0) AS GrandTotal,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(12, 2), 0) AS Variance,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(5, 2), 0) AS TotalDiscount,
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(30, 8), 0) AS TotalSelected
FROM BusinessPartners BP, 
(
QuotationsHeader QH
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (ExchangeRates ER
                    INNER JOIN
                            (SELECT CurrencyCode,
                                    MAX(ExchangeRateDate) AS ExchangeRateDate
                            FROM ExchangeRates
                            WHERE ExchangeRateDate <= '2023/01/04 00:00:00'
                            GROUP BY CurrencyCode
                            ) 
                        ERmax ON ER.CurrencyCode = ERmax.CurrencyCode
                    AND ER.ExchangeRateDate = ERmax.ExchangeRateDate
                        ) 
                    ON ER.CurrencyCode = QH.CurrencyCode
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN BusinessPartners BillingSupplierBP 
    ON BillingSupplierBP.BusinessPartnerCode = QH.BillingSupplierCode,
                           EnquiriesDetail ED,
                           QuotationsDetail QD
WHERE BP.BusinessPartnerCode = QH.SupplierCode
  AND QH.EnquiryNum = QD.EnquiryNum
  AND QH.QuotationNum = QD.QuotationNum
  AND ED.EnquiryNum = QD.EnquiryNum
  AND ED.EnquirylineNum = QD.EnquirylineNum
  AND ED.EnquiryNum = 838
  AND QH.QuotationStatus <> 2
GROUP BY QH.QuotationNum,
         BP.Name,
         BP.ShortName,
         QH.CurrencyCode,
         QH.SupplierCode,
         QH.BillingSupplierCode,
         BillingSupplierBP.ShortName,
         QH.PackagingExpenses,
         QH.DeliveryExpenses,
         QH.OtherExpenses,
         ER.ExchangeRate
HAVING SUM(QD.PriceListValue) <> 0
```

And it returns these results:

[image]

I have added the Execution Plan here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJZHCyXqs

Here is the tables info:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NHPVHD3quvT9LTpAOYlGmcJ8BRID9HO6lNf51ii_h3E/edit?usp=sharing

Edit:

[image]

Edit 2:

```
USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ApplicationProfile]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:03:36 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationProfile](
    [BaseCurrencyCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyAddr1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyAddr2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyAddr3] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyAddr4] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyTelephone] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyFax] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyTelex] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyEmail] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentManagementInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyLogo] [image] NULL,
    [DocumentManagementFilePath] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [LubricantsBPCategory] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [PaintsBPCategory] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [BaseCurrencySuggestionInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExRateDeviation] [numeric](3, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType1Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType2Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType3Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [DataAccessControlActiveInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EnableAutoSaveProcessInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValidateVesselsAccountDataInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProfileID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SMTPAuthenticationInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SMTPEncryptionInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SMTPPassword] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SMTPPortNumber] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [SMTPServer] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SMTPUserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SPDocumentLibrary] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SPServerName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SPServiceName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SPServiceURL] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SPSSP] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AtSeaPortCode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [EmailCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [FaxCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [MobileCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AccEmailCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [InvoicingAddressType] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AOHPhoneCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AttachmentsServerLocalPath] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [AttachmentsServerNetworkPath] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ChemicalTankersVslTypeCode] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CompassMailInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BunkerSupplierBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [BunkerSurveyorBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [InsuranceBrokerBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [UnderwriterBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [DGCalculationFormula] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL,
    [MECalculationFormula] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyReceptionDpt] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CrewingAgencyBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultOnBoardWarehouse] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [EmailFooter] [varchar](5000) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyVesselCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [FWBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [PUAgentBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [PUSupplierBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [CashierCompanyTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [FOSuppliersBPCategory] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [GRSuppliersBPCategory] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [IsCashierRelTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [ManagesRelTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [MngCompanyTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [OwningRelationshipTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [SPVCompanyTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AutoUpdateBPBankDetailsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EUAgentsAppointmentRemarks] [varchar](600) NOT NULL,
    [FBB250CDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [FBB500CDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [HelicopterBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [HoldsSharesRelTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [LaunchingBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [MooringBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [PilotageBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [SHCompanyTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [TelexCDTCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [TowageBPType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [IHCompanyTypeCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [OverrideCachingInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MSOutlookInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DecodeSMTPCredentialsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OverrideSyncUsersWithADInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyWatermark] [image] NULL,
    [NotificationInterval] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NotificationUpdateInterval] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NotificationWarningInterval] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NotifyForUnprocessedMsgInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShowBankDetailsCommentsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [PuEmailCdtCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentMaxFileSize] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UseTls12Ind] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BusinessPartners]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:04:54 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusinessPartners](
    [BusinessPartnerCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ShortName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VatCode] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CountryCode] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Telephone] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Fax] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Telex] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultCurrency] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAccount] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [SupplierInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ChartererInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AgentInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BrokerInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [YardInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AllAccountsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreditTermsType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [CreditTermsDays] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherReference1] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [OtherReference2] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [OwnCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [RelatedBusinessPartner] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedCode1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedCode2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedCode3] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedCode4] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserDefinedCode5] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine3] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LocalAddressNumber] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [LocalAddressStreet] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LocalCity] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LocalInvoiceType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LocalName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LocalProfession] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LocalTaxAuthorityCode] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [LocalZipCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyRestrictedInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType1Ind] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType2Ind] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraBPType3Ind] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FinanciallyActiveInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MinoritiesInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfficePersonnelInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateRecordOpened] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FinancialActivationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EntryNotAllowed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BeneficiaryOPWordingInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChartsPublicationsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChemicalsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LubricantsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PaintsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProvisionsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ServicesInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SparePartsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StoresInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BunkersInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentCode] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [IDNum] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [JobTitle] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [PassportNum] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [GrossRateDecimals] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExcludeFromMYFInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OwnerInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PoolParticipantInd] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EnquiriesDetail]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:05:40 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EnquiriesDetail](
    [EnquiryNum] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [EnquiryLineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ItemDescription] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [RobQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [PmsInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SparesCondition] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InactiveRecInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ComponentCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SubComponentCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ComparisonGroup] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedUnitOfMeasure] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [OptionalQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [DrawingCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [RequisitionLineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequisitionNum] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Grade] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ISOStandard] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCategory1] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCategory2] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [QuantityRangeFrom] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [VesselCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ExchangeRates]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:05:48 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExchangeRates](
    [CurrencyCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ExchangeRateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExchangeRate] [numeric](11, 5) NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[QuotationsHeader]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:06:16 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuotationsHeader](
    [EnquiryNum] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [QuotationNum] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,
    [RfqDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [QuotationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RequestedDeliveryDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SupplierCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [CurrencyCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [SupplierReference] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [PackagingExpenses] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryDays] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryExpenses] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [OtherExpenses] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AttachmentFileName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BerthName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DemurrageRate] [numeric](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Port] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [BillingSupplierCode] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [PaymentDays] [numeric](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [QuotationStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SupplierContactPerson] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentTerms] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[QuotationsDetail]    Script Date: 4/1/2023 4:06:22 μμ ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuotationsDetail](
    [EnquiryNum] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [QuotationNum] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,
    [QuotationLineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EnquiryLineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemCode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [QuotedQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [numeric](15, 5) NOT NULL,
    [UnitPriceInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [numeric](5, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PriceListValue] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [NetValue] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryDays] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DiscountValue] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [LastUser] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ConversionFactor] [numeric](10, 5) NOT NULL,
    [QuotedUnitOfMeasure] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedUnitOfMeasure] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [OptionalUnitPrice] [numeric](15, 5) NOT NULL,
    [PostedUnitPrice] [numeric](15, 5) NOT NULL,
    [PumpingRate] [numeric](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedOptionalQuantity] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [UnitDiscountAmount] [numeric](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ValidToDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FirstUnitPrice] [numeric](15, 5) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryMethodInd] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Grade] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ISOStandard] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCategory1] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCategory2] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [RequestedQuantityRangeFrom] [numeric](9, 3) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins - it's very confusing. Use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Tried removing the `DISTINCT` and it still returns the results in the same time. (Same results thankfully).

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. In addition to query tuning, indexes are key to performance.

Comment: Also it's now *2023*, the ANSI-92 explicit join syntax has been around for *over 30 years*; it's long past time you adopted it.

Comment: I added the execution plan in the post. @DanGuzman

Comment: Your subquery to `ApplicationProfile` would likely be better served as a (ANSI-92) `JOIN` too.

Comment: Looking at that plan, almost every index seek results in a lookup, which suggests that most of your tables don't have a covering index (seems just `EnquiriesDetail` has a covering index).  What indexes do you have on these tables? Can you include the table definitions with the relevant indexes in your question?

Comment: I generally recommend a clustered index on tables unless you have specialized needs for a heap. Choosing the best clustered index is non-trivial due to the trade-offs but can improve performance considerably. To wit, I recently added clustered indexes to a problem database and added page compression too. Overall performance improved by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Larnu sorry to make you wait, I included everything related to the tables in an excel file. I'm keen to understand more on this, as it's my first time going this in depth.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added an excel file if it helps with all the info of the tables used in my query. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I won't be downloading a random file from a stranger on the internet, @Alexander . If you want to include information, use the [edit] feature to include it in the question.

Comment: @Larnu It's an online docs excel file with 191 lines. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: *"use the [edit] feature to include it in the question*"

Comment: I have been trying to understand how to paste the entire excel sheet in the post, however when I try editing the post it says to manually do it line by line adding ":" and "|" and there are many columns and lines to do so. Other thing I could think of is posting multiple screenshots if that is fine. What do you suggest? @Larnu

Comment: T-SQL doesn't tend to have `:` and `|` characters in code, so I'm not sure what you're stating. Just put the DDL in a code block/fence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250837/discussion-between-alexander-and-larnu).

Comment: @Alexander, in other words, just script the CREATE INDEX DDL using SSMS and add it to your question in a code block. The tabular view of the index definitions is not necessary.

Comment: Added the tables create scripts. Is this what is needed?